# Python subprocesses consuming memory

Tags: python, multithreading, subprocess, adafruit

Im trying to be able to set the broadcasting frequency by pressing the left/right button on a hat on a raspberry pi. I use the [PiFmRds](https://github.com/ChristopheJacquet/PiFmRds) library.

But after changing the freq a few times the Pi runs out of memory and i get "Could not allocate memory." error. Do the old subprocesses keep running and consume memory? And if, how do I kill the old subprocesses?

Thanks!!!

(The code is a bit messy im sorry ;) )

```
import os
import board
import busio
import adafruit_character_lcd.character_lcd_rgb_i2c as character_lcd
import time
import subprocess
import sys
import digitalio
import threading
import signal


lcd_columns = 16
lcd_rows = 2
i2c = busio.I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA)
lcd = character_lcd.Character_LCD_RGB_I2C(i2c, lcd_columns, lcd_rows)

freq = 103.3

while True:
    try:
        freq = round(freq, 1)
        bashCommand = "sudo ./pi_fm_rds -audio sound.wav -pi 0000 -freq " + str(freq)

        lcd.clear()
        lcd.message = str(freq)
        transmit.send_signal(signal.SIGINT)

        transmit = subprocess.Popen([bashCommand], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)

        print(freq)

        while lcd.left_button or lcd.right_button == False:
            if lcd.left_button:
                freq = freq - 0.1
                while lcd.left_button == True:
                    pass
                break
        
            if lcd.right_button:
                freq = freq + 0.1
                while lcd.right_button == True:
                    pass
                break

    except ValueError:
        print(ValueError)
        exit()
```

Comment: Reading the source code of pi-fm-rds, it looks like it has to do a pretty substantial amount of [cleanup](https://github.com/ChristopheJacquet/PiFmRds/blob/b0f253232b2c5084c51dc81200e6d1a116221ff2/src/pi_fm_rds.c#L243) on termination. I bet it's taking longer to do that cleanup than it does to start a new process, so it's creating processes faster than it can remove them. `terminate()` is asyncronous, so it returns as soon as it's sent the signal, not when the process is done exiting.

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
import board
import busio
import adafruit_character_lcd.character_lcd_rgb_i2c as character_lcd
import time
import subprocess
import sys
import digitalio
import threading
import signal

lcd_columns = 16
lcd_rows = 2
i2c = busio.I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA)
lcd = character_lcd.Character_LCD_RGB_I2C(i2c, lcd_columns, lcd_rows)
freq = 103.3

#You must start the transmit at the beginning first to guarantee a clean channel
transmit = None

while True:
    try:
        freq = round(freq, 1)
        bashCommand = "sudo ./pi_fm_rds -audio sound.wav -pi 0000 -freq " + str(freq)
        lcd.clear()
        lcd.message = str(freq)
        if transmit is not None:
            transmit.send_signal(signal.SIGINT)

        # Before starting a new process, terminate the previous one if it exists
        if transmit is not None:
            transmit.terminate()
            transmit.wait()  # Wait for the process to finish

        transmit = subprocess.Popen([bashCommand], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)

        print(freq)

        while lcd.left_button or lcd.right_button == False:
            if lcd.left_button:
                freq = freq - 0.1
                while lcd.left_button == True:
                    pass
                break
        
            if lcd.right_button:
                freq = freq + 0.1
                while lcd.right_button == True:
                    pass
                break

    except ValueError:
        print(ValueError)
        exit()
```

Comment: Isn't sending both `SIGINT` and `SIGTERM` redundant? Seems like you only need one or the other.

Comment: Many times it is a necessary redundancy since -SIGINT is the signal sent from the keyboard to interrupt the process and SIGTERM is the default signal sent by the kill command on Unix. Asks the process to close in an orderly manner. This is necessary in case there is a conflict with the peripherals since we are not talking about a conventional PC. I try to skip the mistakes. I know that in another context it would be bad practice but trying raspberry solves the problem.

Comment: In this specific case, SIGINT and SIGTERM are handled by the same signal handler. See https://github.com/ChristopheJacquet/PiFmRds/blob/b0f253232b2c5084c51dc81200e6d1a116221ff2/src/pi_fm_rds.c#L321 I agree that in principle, they could be handled by different signal handlers. In this case, they aren't.

Comment: Thanks. That helpled but I still get the "Could not allocate memory." error. Seems like the precesses still consume memory.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use the gc module that handles garbage collection. We can force a garbage collection after killing the process which could help free the memory that the process was using.I fix the previous problem.

```
import os
import board
import busio
import adafruit_character_lcd.character_lcd_rgb_i2c as character_lcd
import time
import subprocess
import sys
import digitalio
import threading
import signal
import gc  # Import the garbage collector

lcd_columns = 16
lcd_rows = 2
i2c = busio.I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA)
lcd = character_lcd.Character_LCD_RGB_I2C(i2c, lcd_columns, lcd_rows)

freq = 103.3

# Initialize transmit to None at the beginning
transmit = None

while True:
    try:
        freq = round(freq, 1)
        bashCommand = "sudo ./pi_fm_rds -audio sound.wav -pi 0000 -freq " + str(freq)

        lcd.clear()
        lcd.message = str(freq)

        # Before starting a new process, kill the previous one if it exists
        if transmit is not None:
            transmit.kill()
            transmit.wait()  # Wait for the process to finish
            del transmit  # Delete the old process object
            gc.collect()  # Force garbage collection

        transmit = subprocess.Popen([bashCommand], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)

        print(freq)

        while lcd.left_button or lcd.right_button == False:
            if lcd.left_button:
                freq = freq - 0.1
                while lcd.left_button == True:
                    pass
                break
        
            if lcd.right_button:
                freq = freq + 0.1
                while lcd.right_button == True:
                    pass
                break

    except ValueError:
        print(ValueError)
        exit()
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to matter how I try to terminate/kill the code. It keeps running.. I've tried gc too..

Answer (score 1):

you could add a signal handler for the SINGIT and SIGTERM

```
import os
import board
import busio
import adafruit_character_lcd.character_lcd_rgb_i2c as character_lcd
import time
import subprocess
import sys
import digitalio
import threading
import signal
import gc  # Import the garbage collector

# Define a signal handler function. 
def signal_handler(signum, frame):
    print(f"Recibida señal {signum}, limpiando...")
    
    # Here you can add any cleanup logic
    if transmit is not None:
        transmit.kill()
        transmit.wait()
    
    sys.exit(0)

# Register the signal handlers, OR YOU CAN choose 
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, signal_handler)

lcd_columns = 16
lcd_rows = 2
i2c = busio.I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA)
lcd = character_lcd.Character_LCD_RGB_I2C(i2c, lcd_columns, lcd_rows)

freq = 103.3

# Initialize transmit to None at the beginning
transmit = None

while True:
    try:
        freq = round(freq, 1)
        bashCommand = "sudo ./pi_fm_rds -audio sound.wav -pi 0000 -freq " + str(freq)

        lcd.clear()
        lcd.message = str(freq)

        # Before starting a new process, kill the previous one if it exists
        if transmit is not None:
            transmit.kill()
            transmit.wait()  # Wait for the process to finish
            del transmit  # Delete the old process object
            gc.collect()  # Force garbage collection

        transmit = subprocess.Popen([bashCommand], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)

        print(freq)

        while lcd.left_button or lcd.right_button == False:
            if lcd.left_button:
                freq = freq - 0.1
                while lcd.left_button == True:
                    pass
                break
        
            if lcd.right_button:
                freq = freq + 0.1
                while lcd.right_button == True:
                    pass
                break

    except ValueError:
        print(ValueError)
        sys.exit(1)
```